# MVAPICH hangs on MPI_Send for message larger than eager threshold

Tags: c++, mpi, mvapich2

There is a simple program in c++ / mpi (mvapich), which sends an array of type float. When i use MPI_Send,MPI_Ssend,MPI_Rsend ,if the size of the data is more than the eager threshold(64k in my program), then during the call MPI_Send my program hangs. If array is smaller than the threshold, program works fine.Source code is bellow:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    int mype=0,size=1;

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&mype);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);

    int num = 2048*2048;
    float* h_pos = new float[num];


    MPI_Status stat;
    if(mype == 0)
    {
        MPI_Rsend(h_pos, 20000, MPI_FLOAT, 1, 5, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    if(mype == 1)
    {
        printf("%fkb\n", 20000.0f*sizeof(float)/1024);
        MPI_Recv(h_pos, 20000, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 5, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stat);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

I think my settings may be wrong，Parameters is bellow:

```
MVAPICH2 All Parameters
    MV2_COMM_WORLD_LOCAL_RANK           : 0
    PMI_ID                              : 0
    MPIRUN_RSH_LAUNCH                   : 0
    MPISPAWN_GLOBAL_NPROCS              : 2
    MPISPAWN_MPIRUN_HOST                : g718a
    MPISPAWN_MPIRUN_ID                  : 10800
    MPISPAWN_NNODES                     : 1
    MPISPAWN_WORKING_DIR                : /home/g718a/new_workspace/mpi_test
    USE_LINEAR_SSH                      : 1
    PMI_PORT                            : g718a:42714
    MV2_3DTORUS_SUPPORT                 : 0
    MV2_NUM_SA_QUERY_RETRIES            : 20
    MV2_NUM_SLS                         : 8
    MV2_DEFAULT_SERVICE_LEVEL           : 0
    MV2_PATH_SL_QUERY                   : 0
    MV2_USE_QOS                         : 0
    MV2_ALLGATHER_BRUCK_THRESHOLD       : 524288
    MV2_ALLGATHER_RD_THRESHOLD          : 81920
    MV2_ALLGATHER_REVERSE_RANKING       : 1
    MV2_ALLGATHERV_RD_THRESHOLD         : 0
    MV2_ALLREDUCE_2LEVEL_MSG            : 262144
    MV2_ALLREDUCE_SHORT_MSG             : 2048
    MV2_ALLTOALL_MEDIUM_MSG             : 16384
    MV2_ALLTOALL_SMALL_MSG              : 2048
    MV2_ALLTOALL_THROTTLE_FACTOR        : 4
    MV2_BCAST_TWO_LEVEL_SYSTEM_SIZE     : 64
    MV2_GATHER_SWITCH_PT                : 0
    MV2_INTRA_SHMEM_REDUCE_MSG          : 2048
    MV2_KNOMIAL_2LEVEL_BCAST_MESSAGE_SIZE_THRESHOLD : 2048
    MV2_KNOMIAL_2LEVEL_BCAST_SYSTEM_SIZE_THRESHOLD : 64
    MV2_KNOMIAL_INTER_LEADER_THRESHOLD  : 65536
    MV2_KNOMIAL_INTER_NODE_FACTOR       : 4
    MV2_KNOMIAL_INTRA_NODE_FACTOR       : 4
    MV2_KNOMIAL_INTRA_NODE_THRESHOLD    : 131072
    MV2_RED_SCAT_LARGE_MSG              : 524288
    MV2_RED_SCAT_SHORT_MSG              : 64
    MV2_REDUCE_2LEVEL_MSG               : 16384
    MV2_REDUCE_SHORT_MSG                : 8192
    MV2_SCATTER_MEDIUM_MSG              : 0
    MV2_SCATTER_SMALL_MSG               : 0
    MV2_SHMEM_ALLREDUCE_MSG             : 32768
    MV2_SHMEM_COLL_MAX_MSG_SIZE         : 131072
    MV2_SHMEM_COLL_NUM_COMM             : 8
    MV2_SHMEM_COLL_NUM_PROCS            : 2
    MV2_SHMEM_COLL_SPIN_COUNT           : 5
    MV2_SHMEM_REDUCE_MSG                : 4096
    MV2_USE_BCAST_SHORT_MSG             : 16384
    MV2_USE_DIRECT_GATHER               : 1
    MV2_USE_DIRECT_GATHER_SYSTEM_SIZE_MEDIUM : 1024
    MV2_USE_DIRECT_GATHER_SYSTEM_SIZE_SMALL : 384
    MV2_USE_DIRECT_SCATTER              : 1
    MV2_USE_OSU_COLLECTIVES             : 1
    MV2_USE_OSU_NB_COLLECTIVES          : 1
    MV2_USE_KNOMIAL_2LEVEL_BCAST        : 1
    MV2_USE_KNOMIAL_INTER_LEADER_BCAST  : 1
    MV2_USE_SCATTER_RD_INTER_LEADER_BCAST : 1
    MV2_USE_SCATTER_RING_INTER_LEADER_BCAST : 1
    MV2_USE_SHMEM_ALLREDUCE             : 1
    MV2_USE_SHMEM_BARRIER               : 1
    MV2_USE_SHMEM_BCAST                 : 1
    MV2_USE_SHMEM_COLL                  : 1
    MV2_USE_SHMEM_REDUCE                : 1
    MV2_USE_TWO_LEVEL_GATHER            : 1
    MV2_USE_TWO_LEVEL_SCATTER           : 1
    MV2_USE_XOR_ALLTOALL                : 1
    MV2_DEFAULT_SRC_PATH_BITS           : 0
    MV2_DEFAULT_STATIC_RATE             : 0
    MV2_DEFAULT_TIME_OUT                : 67374100
    MV2_DEFAULT_MTU                     : 0
    MV2_DEFAULT_PKEY                    : 0
    MV2_DEFAULT_PORT                    : -1
    MV2_DEFAULT_GID_INDEX               : 0
    MV2_DEFAULT_PSN                     : 0
    MV2_DEFAULT_MAX_RECV_WQE            : 128
    MV2_DEFAULT_MAX_SEND_WQE            : 64
    MV2_DEFAULT_MAX_SG_LIST             : 1
    MV2_DEFAULT_MIN_RNR_TIMER           : 12
    MV2_DEFAULT_QP_OUS_RD_ATOM          : 257
    MV2_DEFAULT_RETRY_COUNT             : 67900423
    MV2_DEFAULT_RNR_RETRY               : 202639111
    MV2_DEFAULT_MAX_CQ_SIZE             : 40000
    MV2_DEFAULT_MAX_RDMA_DST_OPS        : 4
    MV2_INITIAL_PREPOST_DEPTH           : 10
    MV2_IWARP_MULTIPLE_CQ_THRESHOLD     : 32
    MV2_NUM_HCAS                        : 1
    MV2_NUM_NODES_IN_JOB                : 1
    MV2_NUM_PORTS                       : 1
    MV2_NUM_QP_PER_PORT                 : 1
    MV2_MAX_RDMA_CONNECT_ATTEMPTS       : 10
    MV2_ON_DEMAND_UD_INFO_EXCHANGE      : 1
    MV2_PREPOST_DEPTH                   : 64
    MV2_HOMOGENEOUS_CLUSTER             : 0
    MV2_COALESCE_THRESHOLD              : 6
    MV2_DREG_CACHE_LIMIT                : 0
    MV2_IBA_EAGER_THRESHOLD             : 0
    MV2_MAX_INLINE_SIZE                 : 0
    MV2_MAX_R3_PENDING_DATA             : 524288
    MV2_MED_MSG_RAIL_SHARING_POLICY     : 0
    MV2_NDREG_ENTRIES                   : 0
    MV2_NUM_RDMA_BUFFER                 : 0
    MV2_NUM_SPINS_BEFORE_LOCK           : 2000
    MV2_POLLING_LEVEL                   : 1
    MV2_POLLING_SET_LIMIT               : -1
    MV2_POLLING_SET_THRESHOLD           : 256
    MV2_R3_NOCACHE_THRESHOLD            : 32768
    MV2_R3_THRESHOLD                    : 4096
    MV2_RAIL_SHARING_LARGE_MSG_THRESHOLD : 16384
    MV2_RAIL_SHARING_MED_MSG_THRESHOLD  : 2048
    MV2_RAIL_SHARING_POLICY             : 4
    MV2_RDMA_EAGER_LIMIT                : 32
    MV2_RDMA_FAST_PATH_BUF_SIZE         : 4096
    MV2_RDMA_NUM_EXTRA_POLLS            : 1
    MV2_RNDV_EXT_SENDQ_SIZE             : 5
    MV2_RNDV_PROTOCOL                   : 3
    MV2_SMALL_MSG_RAIL_SHARING_POLICY   : 0
    MV2_SPIN_COUNT                      : 5000
    MV2_SRQ_LIMIT                       : 30
    MV2_SRQ_MAX_SIZE                    : 4096
    MV2_SRQ_SIZE                        : 256
    MV2_STRIPING_THRESHOLD              : 8192
    MV2_USE_COALESCE                    : 0
    MV2_USE_XRC                         : 0
    MV2_VBUF_MAX                        : -1
    MV2_VBUF_POOL_SIZE                  : 512
    MV2_VBUF_SECONDARY_POOL_SIZE        : 256
    MV2_VBUF_TOTAL_SIZE                 : 0
    MV2_USE_HWLOC_CPU_BINDING           : 1
    MV2_ENABLE_AFFINITY                 : 1
    MV2_ENABLE_LEASTLOAD                : 0
    MV2_SMP_BATCH_SIZE                  : 8
    MV2_SMP_EAGERSIZE                   : 65537
    MV2_SMPI_LENGTH_QUEUE               : 262144
    MV2_SMP_NUM_SEND_BUFFER             : 256
    MV2_SMP_SEND_BUF_SIZE               : 131072
    MV2_USE_SHARED_MEM                  : 1
    MV2_CUDA_BLOCK_SIZE                 : 0
    MV2_CUDA_NUM_RNDV_BLOCKS            : 8
    MV2_CUDA_VECTOR_OPT                 : 1
    MV2_CUDA_KERNEL_OPT                 : 1
    MV2_EAGER_CUDAHOST_REG              : 0
    MV2_USE_CUDA                        : 1
    MV2_CUDA_NUM_EVENTS                 : 64
    MV2_CUDA_IPC                        : 1
    MV2_CUDA_IPC_THRESHOLD              : 0
    MV2_CUDA_ENABLE_IPC_CACHE           : 0
    MV2_CUDA_IPC_MAX_CACHE_ENTRIES      : 1
    MV2_CUDA_IPC_NUM_STAGE_BUFFERS      : 2
    MV2_CUDA_IPC_STAGE_BUF_SIZE         : 524288
    MV2_CUDA_IPC_BUFFERED               : 1
    MV2_CUDA_IPC_BUFFERED_LIMIT         : 33554432
    MV2_CUDA_IPC_SYNC_LIMIT             : 16384
    MV2_CUDA_USE_NAIVE                  : 1
    MV2_CUDA_REGISTER_NAIVE_BUF         : 524288
    MV2_CUDA_GATHER_NAIVE_LIMIT         : 32768
    MV2_CUDA_SCATTER_NAIVE_LIMIT        : 2048
    MV2_CUDA_ALLGATHER_NAIVE_LIMIT      : 1048576
    MV2_CUDA_ALLGATHERV_NAIVE_LIMIT     : 524288
    MV2_CUDA_ALLTOALL_NAIVE_LIMIT       : 262144
    MV2_CUDA_ALLTOALLV_NAIVE_LIMIT      : 262144
    MV2_CUDA_BCAST_NAIVE_LIMIT          : 2097152
    MV2_CUDA_GATHERV_NAIVE_LIMIT        : 0
    MV2_CUDA_SCATTERV_NAIVE_LIMIT       : 16384
    MV2_CUDA_ALLTOALL_DYNAMIC           : 1
    MV2_CUDA_ALLGATHER_RD_LIMIT         : 1024
    MV2_CUDA_ALLGATHER_FGP              : 1
    MV2_SMP_CUDA_PIPELINE               : 1
    MV2_CUDA_INIT_CONTEXT               : 1
    MV2_SHOW_ENV_INFO                   : 2
    MV2_DEFAULT_PUT_GET_LIST_SIZE       : 200
    MV2_EAGERSIZE_1SC                   : 0
    MV2_GET_FALLBACK_THRESHOLD          : 0
    MV2_PIN_POOL_SIZE                   : 2097152
    MV2_PUT_FALLBACK_THRESHOLD          : 0
    MV2_ASYNC_THREAD_STACK_SIZE         : 1048576
    MV2_THREAD_YIELD_SPIN_THRESHOLD     : 5
    MV2_USE_HUGEPAGES                   : 1
```

and Configurations:

```
 mpiname -a

MVAPICH2 2.0 Fri Jun 20 20:00:00 EDT 2014 ch3:mrail

Compilation
CC: gcc    -DNDEBUG -DNVALGRIND -O2
CXX: g++   -DNDEBUG -DNVALGRIND
F77: no -L/lib -L/lib  
FC: no  

Configuration
-with-device=ch3:mrail --with-rdma=gen2 --enable-cuda --disable-f77 --disable-fc --disable-mcast
```

The program runs on 2 processes:

```
mpirun_rsh -hostfile hosts -n 2 MV2_USE_CUDA=1 MV2_SHOW_ENV_INFO=2 ./myTest
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The [MPI Standard](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.0/mpi30-report.pdf) specifies that

> A send that uses the ready communication mode may be started only if the matching receive is already posted. Otherwise, the operation is erroneous and its outcome is undefined.

In this program there is no guarantee that the `Recv` will be posted before the `Rsend`, so the operation may fail or hang.

Comment: To elaborate on this, the code needs to add a synchronization after the MPI_Recv and before the MPI_Rsend.  A call to MPI_Barrier is complete overkill but sufficient.  Point-to-point synchronization via MPI_Ssend is perhaps the minimum necessary synchronization, but that defeats the purpose of MPI_Rsend in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I have run this on my laptop with 781.2 KiB without any deadlock.  Ran it on a Blue Gene/Q with 781.2 KiB without any deadlock.   So, thanks for the short test case, but I'm sorry I cannot reproduce your issue.  Maybe it's specific to infiniband?

The general solution in this case is to post non-blocking sends and receives.  I can provide code, but you're asking about ready-send and the eager threshold, so I'm pretty sure you know about those already and must have a good reason not to use them...

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your test case using MVAPICH2-2.0 on an InfiniBand system, and I was not able to reproduce the hang. Would you be able to post a debug trace of the process which is hanging?

```
$ gdb attach <PID>
gdb> thread apply all bt
```